# How to use MD5 with the AuthComponent in CakePHP 3.9

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on migrating a web application developed using CakePHP 1.2 I am migrating it to version 3.9.4. The user passwords in the database are all hashed using MD5 but version 3.9.4 uses bcrypt as the default hasher. I want to use MD5 so I can authenticate the users using MD5. I have gone through this [article](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes) and used the LegacyPasswordHasher class as guided in the article but it is not working. Here is how I configured the AuthComponent in AppController.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => ['Form' => [
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Legacy',
                ],
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password',
                ],
            ]],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ],
        ]);
```

And here is my LegcayPasswordHasher class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;

class LegacyPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {
    public function hash($password) {
        return md5($password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
        $userPassword = md5($password);
        return $userPassword === $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

This is the `UserAuthComponent` from the old system. Located in `app/Controller/Component`.

```
class UserAuthComponent extends Component {
    /**
     * This component uses following components
     *
     * @var array
     */
    var $components = array('Session', 'Cookie', 'RequestHandler', 'ControllerList');
    /**
     * configur key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    var $configureKey='User';

    function initialize(Controller $controller) {

    }

    function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
    }

    function startup(Controller $controller = null) {

    }
    /**
     * Called before the controller action.  You can use this method to configure and customize components
     * or perform logic that needs to happen before each controller action.
     *
     * @param object $c current controller object
     * @return void
     */
    function beforeFilter(&$c) {
        UsermgmtInIt($this);
        $user = $this->__getActiveUser();
        $pageRedirect = $c->Session->read('permission_error_redirect');
        $c->Session->delete('permission_error_redirect');
        $controller = $c->params['controller'];
        $action = $c->params['action'];
        $actionUrl = $controller.'/'.$action;
        $requested= (isset($c->params['requested']) && $c->params['requested']==1) ? true : false;
        $permissionFree=array('users/login', 'users/logout', 'users/register', 'users/userVerification', 'users/forgotPassword', 'users/activatePassword', 'pages/display', 'users/accessDenied', 'users/emailVerification','users/admin_login','schools/garminApi','schools/viewActivitymy','schools/viewbonuspointupdate','students/viewclassstudentleader','students/viewclassstudentleaderexport','schools/viewpointsupdate');
        $access =str_replace(' ','',ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$controller))).'/'.$action;
        $allControllers=$this->ControllerList->getControllerWithMethods();
        $errorPage=false;
        if (!in_array($access, $allControllers)) {
            $errorPage=true;
        }
        if(  $action == "viewActivitymy" || $action == "viewActivitymycron" || $action == "viewActivitymycronfitbit"|| $action == "viewActivityfitbit" || $action=="viewPointactivity" || $action =="viewActivitymycron_manual" || $action =="viewbonuspointupdate" || $action =="viewpointsupdate" || $action =="viewclassstudentleader" || $action =="viewclassstudentleaderexport"){
            
        }else{
        if ((empty($pageRedirect) || $actionUrl!='users/login') && !$requested && !in_array($actionUrl, $permissionFree) && !$errorPage) {
            App::import("Model", "UserGroup");
            $userGroupModel = new UserGroup;
            if (!$this->isLogged()) {
                if (!$userGroupModel->isGuestAccess($controller, $action)) {
                    $c->log('permission: actionUrl-'.$actionUrl, LOG_DEBUG);
                    $c->Session->write('permission_error_redirect','/users/login');
                    $c->Session->setFlash('You need to be signed in to view this page.');
                    $cUrl = '/'.$c->params->url;
                    if(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                        $rUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                        $pos =strpos($rUrl, $cUrl);
                        $cUrl=substr($rUrl, $pos, strlen($rUrl));
                    }
                    $c->Session->write('OriginAfterLogin', $cUrl);
                    $c->redirect('/login');
                }
            } else {
                if (!$userGroupModel->isUserGroupAccess($controller, $action, $this->getGroupId())) {
                    $c->log('permission: actionUrl-'.$actionUrl, LOG_DEBUG);
                    $c->Session->write('permission_error_redirect','/users/login');
                     $c->redirect('/accessDenied');
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Used to check whether user is logged in or not
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isLogged() {
        return ($this->getUserId() !== null);
    }
    /**
     * Used to get user from session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->Session->read('UserAuth');
    }
    /**
     * Used to get user id from session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->Session->read('UserAuth.User.id');
    }
    /**
     * Used to get group id from session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getGroupId() {
        return $this->Session->read('UserAuth.User.user_group_id');
    }
    /**
     * Used to get group name from session
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGroupName() {
        return $this->Session->read('UserAuth.UserGroup.name');
    }
    /**
     * Used to check is admin logged in
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function isAdmin() {
        $groupId = $this->Session->read('UserAuth.User.user_group_id');
        if($groupId==ADMIN_GROUP_ID) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Used to check is guest logged in
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function isGuest() {
        $groupId = $this->Session->read('UserAuth.User.user_group_id');
        if(empty($groupId)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Used to make password in hash format
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $pass password of user
     * @return hash
     */
    public function makePassword($pass, $salt=null) {
        return md5(md5($pass).md5($salt));
    }
    /**
     * Used to make salt in hash format
     *
     * @access public
     * @return hash
     */
    public function makeSalt() {
        $rand = mt_rand(0, 32);
        $salt = md5($rand . time());
        return $salt;
    }
    /**
     * Used to maintain login session of user
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $type possible values 'guest', 'cookie', user array
     * @param string $credentials credentials of cookie, default null
     * @return array
     */
    public function login($type = 'guest', $credentials = null) {
        $user=array();
        if (is_string($type) && ($type=='guest' || $type=='cookie')) {
            App::import("Model", "User");
            $userModel = new User;
            $user = $userModel->authsomeLogin($type, $credentials);
        } elseif (is_array($type)) {
            $user =$type;
        }
        Configure::write($this->configureKey, $user);
        $this->Session->write('UserAuth', $user);
        return $user;
    }
    /**
     * Used to delete user session and cookie
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function logout() {
        $this->Session->delete('UserAuth');
        Configure::write($this->configureKey, array());
        $this->Cookie->delete(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME);
    }
    /**
     * Used to persist cookie for remember me functionality
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $duration duration of cookie life time on user's machine
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function persist($duration = '2 weeks') {
        App::import("Model", "User");
        $userModel = new User;
        $token = $userModel->authsomePersist($this->getUserId(), $duration);
        $token = $token.':'.$duration;
        return $this->Cookie->write(
            LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME,
            $token,
            true, // encrypt = true
            $duration
        );
    }
    /**
     * Used to check user's session if user's session is not available then it tries to get login from cookie if it exist
     *
     * @access private
     * @return array
     */
    private function __getActiveUser() {
        $user = Configure::read($this->configureKey);
        if (!empty($user)) {
            return $user;
        }

        $this->__useSession() || $this->__useCookieToken() || $this->__useGuestAccount();

        $user = Configure::read($this->configureKey);
        if (is_null($user)) {
            throw new Exception(
                'Unable to initilize user'
            );
        }
        return $user;
    }
    /**
     * Used to get user from session
     *
     * @access private
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function __useSession() {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            return false;
        }
        Configure::write($this->configureKey, $user);
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Used to get login from cookie
     *
     * @access private
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function __useCookieToken() {
        $token = $this->Cookie->read(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME);
        if (!$token) {
            return false;
        }
        $user=false;
        // Extract the duration appendix from the token
        if(strpos($token, ":") !==false) {
            $tokenParts = split(':', $token);
            $duration = array_pop($tokenParts);
            $token = join(':', $tokenParts);
            $user = $this->login('cookie', compact('token', 'duration'));
            // Delete the cookie once its been used
        }
        $this->Cookie->delete(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME);
        if (!$user) {
            return;
        }
        $this->persist($duration);
        return (bool)$user;
    }
    /**
     * Used to get login as guest
     *
     * @access private
     * @return array
     */
    private function __useGuestAccount() {
        return $this->login('guest');
    }
}
```

And this is the `User` Model located at `app/Mode/` in the old codebase.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class User extends AppModel {

    /**
     * This model belongs to following models
     *
     * @var array
     */
    var $belongsTo = array('UserGroup');
    /**
     * This model has following models
     *
     * @var array
     */
    var $hasMany = array('LoginToken'=>array('className'=>'LoginToken','limit' =>1));
    /**
     * model validation array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    var $validate = array();
    /**
     * UsetAuth component object
     *
     * @var object
     */
    var $userAuth;
    /**
     * model validation array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    function LoginValidate() {
        $validate1 = array(
                'email'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter email or username')
                    ),
                'password'=>array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter password')
                    )
            );
        $this->validate=$validate1;
        return $this->validates();
    }
    /**
     * model validation array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    function RegisterValidate() {
        $validate1 = array(
                //"user_group_id" => array(
                    //'rule' => array('comparison', '!=', 0),
                    //'message'=> 'Please select group'),
                'school_name'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter school name',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustUnique'=>array(
                        'rule' =>'isUnique',
                        'message' =>'This school name already taken',
                    'last'=>true),
                    // 'mustBeLonger'=>array(
                    //  'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
                    //  'message'=> 'Username must be greater than 3 characters',
                    //  'last'=>true),
                    ),
                'first_name'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter administrator first name')
                    ),
                'last_name'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'on' => 'create',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter administrator last name')
                    ),
                'email'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter email',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustBeEmail'=> array(
                        'rule' => array('email'),
                        'message' => 'Please enter valid email',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustUnique'=>array(
                        'rule' =>'isUnique',
                        'message' =>'This email is already registered',
                        )
                    ),
                'oldpassword'=>array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter old password',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustMatch'=>array(
                        'rule' => array('verifyOldPass'),
                        'message' => 'Please enter correct old password'),
                    ),
                'password'=>array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter password',
                        'on' => 'create',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustBeLonger'=>array(
                        'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
                        'message'=> 'Password must be greater than 5 characters',
                        'on' => 'create',
                        'last'=>true),
                    'mustMatch'=>array(
                        'rule' => array('verifies'),
                        'message' => 'Both passwords must match'),
                        //'on' => 'create'
                    ),
                'number_of_student'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter number of student')
                    ),
                'tracker'=> array(
                    'mustNotEmpty'=>array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message'=> 'Please enter tracker number')
                    ),
                'captcha'=>array(
                    'mustMatch'=>array(
                        'rule' => array('recaptchaValidate'),
                        'message' => ''),
                    )
            );
        $this->validate=$validate1;
        return $this->validates();
    }
    /**
     * Used to validate captcha
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function recaptchaValidate() {
        App::import("Vendor", "recaptcha/recaptchalib");
        $recaptcha_challenge_field = (isset($_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'])) ? $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'] : "";
        $recaptcha_response_field = (isset($_POST['recaptcha_response_field'])) ? $_POST['recaptcha_response_field'] : "";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer(PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_RECAPTCHA, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $recaptcha_challenge_field, $recaptcha_response_field);
        $error = $resp->error;
        if(!$resp->is_valid) {
            $this->validationErrors['captcha'][0]=$error;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Used to match passwords
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function verifies() {
        return ($this->data['User']['password']===$this->data['User']['cpassword']);
    }
    /**
     * Used to match old password
     *
     * @access public
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function verifyOldPass() {
        $userId = $this->userAuth->getUserId();
        $user = $this->findById($userId);
        $oldpass=$this->userAuth->makePassword($this->data['User']['oldpassword'], $user['User']['salt']);
        return ($user['User']['password']===$oldpass);
    }
    /**
     * Used to send registration mail to user
     *
     * @access public
     * @param array $user user detail array
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendRegistrationMail($user) {
    
        // $user['User']['email'];
        // send email to newly created user
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $userId=$user['User']['id'];
        $email->config('smtp');
        $fromConfig = 'pradeep.singh@udaantechnologies.com';
        $fromNameConfig = 'Pradeep';
        $email->from(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->sender(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->to($user['User']['email']);
        $email->subject('Your registration is complete');
        //$email->transport('Debug');
        $body="Welcome ".$user['User']['first_name'].", Thank you for your registration on ".'http://localhost/garmin/register'." \n\n Thanks,\n".EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        try{
            $result = $email->send($body);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // we could not send the email, ignore it
            $result="Could not send registration email to userid-".$userId;
        }
        $this->log($result, LOG_DEBUG);
    }
    /**
     * Used to send email verification mail to user
     *
     * @access public
     * @param array $user user detail array
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendVerificationMail($user) {
        $userId=$user['User']['id'];
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('smtp');
        $fromConfig = 'pradeep.singh@udaantechnologies.com';
        $fromNameConfig = 'Pradeep';
        $email->from(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->sender(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->to($user['User']['email']);
        $email->subject('Email Verification Mail');
        $activate_key = $this->getActivationKey($user['User']['password']);
        $link = Router::url("/userVerification?ident=$userId&activate=$activate_key",true);
        $body="Hi, Click the link below to complete your registration \n\n ".$link;
        try{
            $result = $email->send($body);
        } catch (Exception $ex){
            // we could not send the email, ignore it
            $result="Could not send verification email to userid-".$userId;
        }
        $this->log($result, LOG_DEBUG);
    }
    /**
     * Used to generate activation key
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $password user password
     * @return hash
     */
    public function getActivationKey($password) {
        $salt = Configure::read ( "Security.salt" );
        return md5(md5($password).$salt);
    }
    /**
     * Used to send forgot password mail to user
     *
     * @access public
     * @param array $user user detail
     * @return void
     */
    public function forgotPassword($user) {
        $userId=$user['User']['id'];
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $fromConfig = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
        $fromNameConfig = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        $email->from(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->sender(array( $fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
        $email->to($user['User']['email']);
        $email->subject(EMAIL_FROM_NAME.': Request to Reset Your Password');
        $activate_key = $this->getActivationKey($user['User']['password']);
        $link = Router::url("/activatePassword?ident=$userId&activate=$activate_key",true);
        $body= "Welcome ".$user['User']['first_name'].", let's help you get signed in

You have requested to have your password reset on ".EMAIL_FROM_NAME.". Please click the link below to reset your password now :

".$link."


If above link does not work please copy and paste the URL link (above) into your browser address bar to get to the Page to reset password

Choose a password you can remember and please keep it secure.

Thanks,\n".

EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        try{
            $result = $email->send($body);
        } catch (Exception $ex){
            // we could not send the email, ignore it
            $result="Could not send forgot password email to userid-".$userId;
        }
        $this->log($result, LOG_DEBUG);
    }
    /**
     * Used to mark cookie used
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $credentials
     * @return array
     */
    public function authsomeLogin($type, $credentials = array()) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'guest':
                // You can return any non-null value here, if you don't
                // have a guest account, just return an empty array
                return array();
            case 'cookie':
                $loginToken=false;
                if(strpos($credentials['token'], ":") !==false) {
                    list($token, $userId) = split(':', $credentials['token']);
                    $duration = $credentials['duration'];

                    $loginToken = $this->LoginToken->find('first', array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'user_id' => $userId,
                            'token' => $token,
                            'duration' => $duration,
                            'used' => false,
                            'expires <=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($duration)),
                        ),
                        'contain' => false
                    ));
                }
                if (!$loginToken) {
                    return false;
                }
                $loginToken['LoginToken']['used'] = true;
                $this->LoginToken->save($loginToken);

                $conditions = array(
                    'User.id' => $loginToken['LoginToken']['user_id']
                );
            break;
            default:
                return array();
        }
        return $this->find('first', compact('conditions'));
    }
    /**
     * Used to generate cookie token
     *
     * @access public
     * @param integer $userId user id
     * @param string $duration cookie persist life time
     * @return string
     */
    public function authsomePersist($userId, $duration) {
        $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->LoginToken->create(array(
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'token' => $token,
            'duration' => $duration,
            'expires' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($duration)),
        ));
        $this->LoginToken->save();
        return "${token}:${userId}";
    }
    /**
     * Used to get name by user id
     *
     * @access public
     * @param integer $userId user id
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameById($userId) {
        $res = $this->findById($userId);
        $name=(!empty($res)) ? ($res['User']['first_name'].' '.$res['User']['last_name']) : '';
        return $name;
    }
    /**
     * Used to check users by group id
     *
     * @access public
     * @param integer $groupId user id
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isUserAssociatedWithGroup($groupId) {
        $res = $this->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('User.user_group_id'=>$groupId)));
        if(!empty($res)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this the [UserController](https://pastebin.com/NXL8dQMS) located at `app/Controller` in the old codebase.

Looking forward to your guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you really shouldn't use the deprecated auth component anymore, and that for outdated hashing algorithms that aren't bound to legacy applications, you should use the fallback hasher to slowly migrate the hashes to a secure algorithm... what does "_doesn't work_" mean? What _exactly_ is happening, and what _exactly_ do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @ndm I know I shouldn't use the outdated hashing algorithms but for the time being I am stuck with using it as the database contains the users with a md5 hashed password. I will migrate it to the default hashing algorithm but for now i need it to work with MD5. "doesn't Work" means that as per documentation I use the LegacyPasswordHasher class and but it isn't authenticating the users and not logging them in.

Comment: What hashing setup is the old application using? Does it explicitly set MD5 as the default algorithm? Does it use any custom authentication code? And are you 100% sure that it's plain MD5 hashes in the database? Even in 1.2 the default was to use a salted hash, and `sha1` and `sha256` were preferred over `md5`.

Comment: @ndm ... I believe that it was using md5 hashes and it was using a UserAuthComponent ... here is a image of the database https://ibb.co/XzFQ8JH

Comment: Well that certainly looks like per user/row salts (and md5). You should investigate if that is the case, ie check what `UserAuthComponent` does with the salts, and see if you need to / can replicate it in your application - with hashers you'd most likely have to update the database, for example prepending the salt to the password, so that the hasher has access to both and is able to generate a hash for comparison accordingly.

Comment: @ndm ... Ideally I would like to deprecate that UserAuthComponent because it was developed a log time ago and the code within is a bit unreadable

Comment: I'd certainly drop using the auth component altogether, as mentioned initially, the new authentication plugin is way more versatile and properly separated :)